# set the Id of an object to be the next available row in DB?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, database, orm

Here is my code:

```
("document").ready(function() {

    $('.register').click(function() {
        var user_name = $("#username").val();
        $.getJSON("/api/Users/GetByUserName/" + user_name)
            .done(function() {
                alert("user name already exist!");
            })
            .fail(function () {
                var usersUri = "/api/Users";
                self.addUser = function () {
                    var user = {
                        Id : ---------???
                        UserName: $("#username").val(),
                        Email: $("#email").val(),
                        Password: $("#password").val(),
                        Wins: 0
                        loses: 0
                    };
                    $.post(usersUri, user).done(function (item) {
                        self.books.push(item);
                    });
                }

            });
    });
});
```

I have Db with the following fields: "id, userName, email, password, wins, loses".
now I want the Id of the new user to be the number if the next available row.
what is the best way?
Thanks!

Comment: why you need to insert next available row id in DB? Just set id as unique primary key, DB will automatically insert it in increment way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you wouldn't assign Id's from the client App but from the Server.

So in your POST API code you can decide what type of Id you want, this can be an auto increment or a GUID or other formats depending on your database.

If you want the next available integer number, first you make your Id on table Users an auto increment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128433/add-autoincrement-to-existing-pk

After that it doesn't matter if you use an ORM or a SQL command you don't need to specify the Id when creating the new record.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good design to assign `Id` on client side. Client shouldn't care about Id. Server should assign first available record Id (can be done automatically in DB with identity primary key) and then, if needed, this Id can be sent back to client with already inserted object.